# using or in mysql and merging columns

Tags: sql, mysql, merge

I can select using or with the sql statement

```
select f.userid, f.friend_userid from friends f where userid = 1 or friend_userid = 1;
```

now either userid or friend_userid is returning 1.

i want the two columns i.e userid and friend_userid to get merged

into a single column without 1 
such that only one row is displayed...

the output i m getting is...

userid | friend_userid

1 | 2

1 | 7

1 | 5

12|1

24 | 1

I want to get displayed like...

userid

2

7

5

12

24

I m using mysql....

Thanks

Pradyut
India

Comment: Do you mean to say you want rows where neither `userid` or `friend_userid` are 1?

Comment: Can you sow the structure of the table and how many rows it will return? I mean to say, is there only one row each for "userid = 1" and "friend_userid = 1" or for any such value given to them?

Comment: @mark yes... either userid or friend_userid is returning 1. i want the
two columns i.e userid and friend_userid to get merged into a single column without 1. thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need the column friend_userid where condition "UserId=1" is met and UserId column when "friend_userid=1" condition is met. Write the following query:

```
select f.friend_userid as userId from friends f where f.userid = 1 
UNION
select f.userid as userId from friends f where f.friend_userid = 1;
```

And you get what you wanted.

Comment: great thanks for the help... i just sorted it out...
and it was the same as your answer...thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want a join, probably a `LEFT JOIN`, between two instances of table `friends`.  If the fields other than `userid` and `friend_userid` are, say, `a` and `b` (you don't tell us and it's impossible to guess:

```
SELECT f.a, f.b, f1.a, f1.b
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN friends f` ON (f.userid = f1.friend_userid)
WHERE f.userid = 1
```

Comment: no i just want the user_id or the friend_userid only...but the output should not return 1 as in my case...i just edited the question...

Answer (score 0):

with the sql

```
 select f.userid, f.friend_userid from friends f where userid = 1 or friend_userid = 1;
```

the output i m getting is...

userid      |     friend_userid

1     | 2

1   | 7

1 | 5

12|1

24 | 1

I want to get displayed like...

userid

2

7

5

12

24

thanks
Pradyut